# Set a request refresh rate in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was working on a very mini project basically to make a small applet that would display the current price of bitcoin

In the problem guide, we were asked to display the bitcoin price when it changes like so

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from termcolor import colored as color
TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'

def get_latest_crypto_price(crypto):

  response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL+crypto)
  response_json = response.json()

  return float(response_json[0]['price_usd'])

def main():

  last_price = -1

  while True:

    crypto = 'bitcoin'
    price = np.round(get_latest_crypto_price(crypto) , 2)

    if price != last_price:
      print(color('Bitcoin price: ' + str(price), 'red'))
      last_price = price

main()
```

What I would like to know is if there is any way I can set the terminal to output the current value of bitcoin say every five seconds rather than having an output dependent on the price changing?

Comment: Remove the `if price != last_price:` condition and add `import time` and `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: Ah ok I knew that the last if-statement was what was controlling that, is time a built-in library or is it something I would need to download with pip?

Comment: time is built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
while 1: # or true as you done
    time.sleep(1) # then wait one second
```

cheers

Comment: and this `time.sleep(1)` would take the place of that final if-statement?